# AWS websockets: disconnect roomIds

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im creating a chat application using AWS websockets and it allows users to join a room with a randomly generated 4 digit code.

```
//roomId : [list of connectionIds]
UXS4: [connectionId1, connectionId2...]
```

The problem i'm running into is that when a user disconnects from a chat room, I have no way of passing what room they were in to the $disconnect endpoint.

tldr: Is there some way to pass data to the $disconnect endpoint in AWS WebSockets?

Comment: Did you try to do anything before asking this question? When you add $disconnect route in Gateway, there are many points about content and payload. So it should be possible to send data.

Comment: Of course thats why i asked the question here :<


On the docs it says "The $disconnect route is executed after the connection is closed." which to me means there there is no way to send data.

If you have somehing that says otherwise id love to read it as that is what my question is about!

cheers!

Comment: So what did you try to do and why/how it didn't work?

Comment: We circumvented the issue by storing connnectionid -> roomId in a separate table.  Thanks sooooo much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the "sourceIp" address within the requestContext identity that comes with the $disconnect event?

Or have the authorizer add values to the requestContext, which will show up in the "authorizer" part of the "requestContext" with the $disconnect event. Like so:

```
"requestContext": {
    "routeKey": "$disconnect",
    "authorizer": {
        "number": "1",
        "happy": "true",
        "client": "big-client",
        "principalId": "7p0f815hneebfebh13jmaonees"
    },
    "messageId": null,
    "eventType": "DISCONNECT",
...
```